# Jmeter using opendJDK on Windows system

Tags: jmeter, adoptopenjdk

After oracle java has become paid. I have Uninstalled oracle JDK and installed openJDK but now when I try to open JMeter, I get the following error: "Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation. errorlevel=2" .. Can someone please let me know how do I make JMeter work with open JDK on my windows system.

I tried changing the path JAVA_HOME to point to open JDK but I still get same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter which [JDK vendor/build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK#OpenJDK_builds) you prefer (Oracle, Microsoft, Eclipse, Amazon, Liberica, whatever) you need to have `java.exe` executable in your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

So if you do something like:

```
set PATH=c:\path\to\your\openjdk\installation\folder\bin;%PATH%
```

and then launch JMeter from that command prompt - it will be successful (hopefully). If it helps - you can add the above line to jmeter.bat startup script to make the change permanent or [amend your PATH environment variable](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html) using any other way.

More information: [JMeter Installation: How to Get Started](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)